# How get language switcher working when using facet api pretty paths?

Tags: i18n-l10n, search

I have a multilingual website where i use facet api pretty paths to get nice urls for the facets.
This looks like
www.example.com/search/color/red
when i filter my search results for the color red.
The working url for this in german would be
www.example.com/de/search/color/rot
(i know, search and color is not translated but this is another problem)
So the problem now is that when i switch the language from english to german the language switcher uses the following url
www.example.com/de/search/color/red
which will not work.
As a workaround i could use the option from facet api pretty paths to use the tid in the urls which would look like this
www.example.com/search/color/red-123
The problem with this solution is that this will lead in multiple working urls for the same content (duplicated content) because he will only use 123 for filtering.

So anyone an idea how to get this working?